# Loop not quite working java

Tags: java

I am new to stackoverflow. First I would like the program to loop with a price, then a question(enter another price?), price, then a question and so on. Below is the output.

```
Please enter a price: 
33
Enter another price? 
y
Please enter a price: 
66
Please enter a price: 
99
Please enter a price: 
22
```

However it will keep looping at the end with "Please enter a price:". I want it to do:

```
Please enter a price: 
33
Enter another price? 
y
Please enter a price: 
66
Enter another price? 
y
Please enter a price: 
22
```

Can anyone help me with this? Also, sometimes the average does not update fully. Thanks :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadInPrice {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int integer = 0;
    int count = 0; 
    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0; 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String addPrice;

    System.out.println("Please enter a price: ");
    integer = input.nextInt();

    do { 
        System.out.println("Enter another price? ");
        addPrice = input.next();
        while (addPrice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) { // change this line to while user response = no etc may need a enter another number?
            count = count + 1;  
            sum = sum + integer; 
            System.out.println("Please enter a price: ");
            integer = input.nextInt();
        }

    }
    while (addPrice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    average = sum / count;
    System.out.println("Average = " + average);

    input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Using a debugger will help you to see and understand the flow of your program better.

Comment: any debuggers you recommend in particular?

Comment: I use Eclipse. http://www.eclipse.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace your `while` with an `if`

```
if (addPrice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) { // change this line to while user response = no etc may need a enter another number?
  count = count + 1;  
  sum = sum + integer; 
  System.out.println("Please enter a price: ");
  integer = input.nextInt();
}
```

In fact, `addPrice` is not modified within your second `while` loop, and so you have an infinite loop.

In order to do the averaged price, you're in the right way but not in the right place :P
`count = count +1` and `sum = sum + integer` should be done after each `integer = input.nextInt()`. In your current code, you don't increment the counter and don't add the integer for the last input.

```
System.out.println("Please enter a price: ");
integer = input.nextInt();
count++ ; // count = count +1
sum += integer ; // sum = sum + integer
do { 
    System.out.println("Enter another price? ");
    addPrice = input.next();
    while (addPrice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) { // change this line to while user response = no etc may need a enter another number?
        System.out.println("Please enter a price: ");
        integer = input.nextInt();
        count++ ; // count = count +1
        sum += integer ; // sum = sum + integer
    }

}
while (addPrice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Finally here is a improved version which avoid the use of `if`.

```
int sum = 0;
int integer = 0;
String addPrice = "Y";
while( "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(addPrice) ) {
   System.out.println("Please enter a price: ");
   integer = input.next();
   sum += integer ;
   count++;        
   System.out.println("Enter another price? ");
   addPrice = input.next();
}
int avg = sum / count ;
```

Comment: Many thanks, sorry one more question, would you have any idea on how to show the minimum and maximum value the user has entered?

Comment: @JaVa Declare a `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE`, a `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE`. In my `while` loop, check if integer is greater than `max` or lesser than `min`, and store it in `max` or `min`. Welcome in the wonderful world of programming =)

Comment: this is great thanks, if I wanted to be fancy and add a feature which count up all of the numbers entered should I use something like:
forfor(count =0; count < num; count++) and do sum += num

Answer (score 0):

i think you want something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReadInPrice {

public static void main(String[] args) {

int integer = 0;
int count = 0; 
double sum = 0;
double average = 0; 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String addPrice = "Y";


while (addPrice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
    System.out.println("Please enter a price: ");
    integer = input.nextInt();
    count++;  
    sum += integer; 
    System.out.println("Enter another price? ");
    addPrice = input.next();
}
average = sum / count;
System.out.println("Average = " + average);

input.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is change your logic a bit.  You need to repeat two actions, entering a price and asking if the user wants to enter another price.  Only one loop is required for this.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a price: ");
    integer = input.nextInt();

    count = count + 1;
    sum = sum + integer;

    System.out.println("Enter another price? ");
    addPrice = input.next();
} while (addPrice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Comment: And that fixes the average issue. Thanks

Comment: Would you have any idea on how to show the minimum and maximum value the user has entered?

Comment: You would need two more variables, min and max.  Each time they enter a number you'd need to compare it to the min and the max.  If the number is less than min, set min to that number.  If the number is greater than max, set max to that number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**EDIT** Added min and max.

```
    public class ReadInPrice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //better to use 2 scanners when dealing with both string and int
        //one for string ; one for ints
        Scanner strScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner intScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean enter = true;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max=0;

        while (enter) { //while user wants to keep adding numbers
            System.out.println("Please enter a price: ");
            int price = intScanner.nextInt();

            if(price < min)
                min=price;

            if(price > max)
                max=price;

            sum += price;
            count++;
            System.out.println("Enter another price? ");
            String answer = strScanner.nextLine();
            if (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                enter = false; //user doesn't want to keep adding numbers - exit while loop
        }
        double average = (double)sum / count;
        System.out.println("Average = " + average);
        System.out.println("Min = " + min);
        System.out.println("Max = " + max);
        strScanner.close();
        intScanner.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, is there a way to count up all the numbers entered?

Comment: @JaVa you already count the numbers entered in the count variable. Just display that as well at the end.